# Memory allocation related tags clarification

Tags: discussion

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205406/memory-allocation-c-sharp-specific-case) and couldn't easily figure out which memory allocation related tag would be best for it. Also, there seem to be a few tags similar to each other and some of them have no description. I'm not sure but I think they might be in order for some cleanup.

Comment: More important than the tags is fixing the Formatting Overflow going on with that question and its answers. It looks like someone just discovered bold, italic, and inline code formatting, and then proceeded to vomit it all over the place.

Comment: @CodyGray *but* `it` **makes** `my` ***text*** **look** `professional` *!*

Comment: Do we need another tag anyway? Seems like there are plenty on there already...

Comment: I'm not talking about another tag, but about how well the existing tags are described and used. Also asking to properly retag if somebody understands which tag would be appropriate.